# Pagination not working with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination

I have this code for a category page rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /category\.php\?catid=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/store/%1? [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^store/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ category.php?catid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

So `www.example.com/store`
is the rewrite for `store.php`

and `www.example.com/store/lights`
is the rewrite for `category.php`

Filters with results are working ok in the search query both for store and category, ex:

```
http://www.example.com/store/lights?title=phillips&searching=
```

The problem is that in the pagination links in both pages are going to the root folder, the href link is like this for both store and category:

```
http://www.example.com/?title=phillips&searching=&pag=2
```

How can i solve this?

```
Pagination function:
function paginationStore($query,$per_page=10,$page=1,$url='?'){  
    global $dbc;
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query} as t WHERE prod_activo ='1'";
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($dbc,$query));
    $total = $row['num'];
    $adjacents = "2";

    $prevlabel = "&lsaquo; Anterior";
    $nextlabel = "Siguiente &rsaquo;";

    $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page); 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;                             

    $prev = $page - 1;                       
    $next = $page + 1;

    $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);

    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1; // //last page minus 1

    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1){  
        $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination pull-right' style='clear:both;'>";
        //$pagination .= "<li class='page_info'>Page {$page} of {$lastpage}</li>";

            if ($page > 1) $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}pag={$prev}'>{$prevlabel}</a></li>";

        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)){  
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++){
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a>{$counter}</a></li>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}pag={$counter}'>{$counter}</a></li>";                
            }

        } elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)){

            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2)) {

                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++){
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a>{$counter}</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}pag={$counter}'>{$counter}</a></li>";                
                }
                $pagination.= "<li class='disabled'><a href='#'>...</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}pag={$lpm1}'>{$lpm1}</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}pag={$lastpage}'>{$lastpage}</a></li>"; 

            } elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2)) {

                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}pag=1'>1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}pag=2'>2</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li class='disabled'><a href='#'>...</a></li>";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++) {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a>{$counter}</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}pag={$counter}'>{$counter}</a></li>";                
                }
                $pagination.= "<li class='disabled'><a href='#'>...</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}pag={$lpm1}'>{$lpm1}</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}pag={$lastpage}'>{$lastpage}</a></li>";    

            } else {

                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}pag=1'>1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}pag=2'>2</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li class='disabled'><a href='#'>...</a></li>";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a>{$counter}</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}pag={$counter}'>{$counter}</a></li>";                
                }
            }
        }

            if ($page < $counter - 1) $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}pag={$next}'>{$nextlabel}</a></li>";

        $pagination.= "</ul>";     
    }

    return $pagination;
}
```

Database query script for the categories:

```
<?php
require_once ('inc/db.php');
include_once ('inc/funciones.php');


$category = str_replace("-"," ",$_GET["catid"]);

$catquery = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM tienda_categorias WHERE cat_nombre='{$category}'");    

while ($raw = mysqli_fetch_array($catquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $cat = $raw['cat_id'];
        }           


$page = (int)(!isset($_GET["pag"]) ? 1 : $_GET["pag"]);
if ($page <= 0) $page = 1;

$per_page = 4; // Set how many records do you want to display per page.

$startpoint = ($page * $per_page) - $per_page;

$statement = "tienda_prod";

$filtros = '';
$url_filtros = '?';

if(isset($_GET['searching'])) {
    //VALIDACION TITULO
    if (isset($_GET['title'])) {
        $title = trim($_GET["title"]);

        $title = str_replace('%','', $title);
        $title = str_replace('_','', $title);
        $title = str_replace('+','', $title);
        if (preg_match ("([^ñÑa-zA-Z0-9\s]|)", $title) && strlen($title) >= 0) {
            $filtros = " AND prod_titulo LIKE '%{$title}%'";
            $url_filtros .= 'title='.$title;

        } else {
            echo '<p class="alert alert-danger">Ingrese un titulo correcto</p>';
        }
    }
    if(isset($_GET['subcat']) && $_GET['subcat'] != 0){
        $subcategoria = $_GET['subcat'];
        $filtros .= " AND t.subcat_id ={$subcategoria}";
        if (isset($_GET['title'])) $url_filtros .= '&';
        $url_filtros .= 'subcategoria='.$subcategoria;
    }
    if(isset($_GET['condicion']) && $_GET['condicion'] != ''){
        $condicion = $_GET['condicion'];
        $condicion = isset($_GET["condicion"]) ? $_GET["condicion"] : "";
        $filtros .= " AND prod_condicion ='{$condicion}'";
        if (isset($_GET['title'])) $url_filtros .= '&';
        $url_filtros .= 'condicion='.$condicion;
    }
    //Validacion de provincia
    if(isset($_GET['permuta']) && $_GET['permuta'] != 0){
        $permuta = $_GET['permuta'];
        $filtros .= " AND prod_permuta='{$permuta}'";
        if (isset($_GET['title']) || isset($_GET['permuta'])) $url_filtros .= '&';
        $url_filtros .= 'permuta='.$permuta;
    }
    $url_filtros .= '&searching=&';
}

$results = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT t.prod_id, t.cat_id, t.subcat_id, t.prod_titulo, t.prod_descripcion, t.prod_precio, t.prod_moneda, t.prod_condicion, t.prod_permuta, t.prod_marca_id, t.prod_destacado, m.marca_nombre, DATE_FORMAT(t.prod_fechacreado, '%d/%m/%Y') AS fc FROM {$statement} AS t LEFT JOIN tienda_marcas AS m ON t.prod_marca_id = m.marca_id WHERE t.prod_activo ='1' AND t.cat_id = {$cat} {$filtros} ORDER BY t.prod_fechacreado DESC LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page}");

$totalRows = mysqli_num_rows($results);
if ($totalRows == 0){ // Si no encuentra registros, muestra la notificacion correspondiente
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><span>No existen articulos en venta para esta categoría</span><div class="col-separador-m"></div><span><button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Publica tu venta <strong>GRATIS</strong></button></span></div>';
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
//var_dump($row);
if($row['prod_precio']==1){
    $moneda = 'U$D';
}else{
    $moneda = '$';
};
if($row['prod_condicion']==0){
    $condicion = 'nuevo';
}else{
    $condicion = 'usado';
}
if($row['prod_destacado']==1){
    $destacado = '<div id="badge">
              <div class="gem-top-right"></div>
              <div class="gem-top-left"></div>
              <div class="gem-bottom-right"></div>
              <div class="gem-bottom-left"></div>
            </div>';
}else{
    $destacado = '';
}

  echo '<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 column productbox">
            '. $destacado .'
            <div class="ribbon-wrapper"><div class="ribbon-'.$condicion.'">'.$condicion.'</div></div>
            <a href="store/' . $row['cat_id'] . '-' . sanitizarURL($row['prod_titulo']) .'-da' . $row['prod_id'] . '">
                <img src="https://unsplash.it/270/270/?random=0" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
            <div class="product-info">
                <div class="product-title">
                    <a href="store/' . $row['cat_id'] . '-' . sanitizarURL($row['prod_titulo']) .'-da' . $row['prod_id'] . '">'. $row['prod_titulo'] . '</a>
                </div>
                <div class="product-price">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <a href="store/' . $row['cat_id'] . '-' . sanitizarURL($row['prod_titulo']) .'-da' . $row['prod_id'] . '" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" role="button">Ver</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pricetext">'.$moneda.''. $row['prod_precio'] . '</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-separador-s"></div>
            </div>
        </div>';

    }   
    echo paginationStore( $statement, $per_page,$page, $url_filtros, $filtros);
?>
```

Comment: Your link is using `index.php` instead of `store/`. Maybe it should be `http://www.example.com/store/?title=phillips&searching=&pag=2`. Also Your query string looks wrong. Shouldn't it be `searching=&pag=2 `. Missing an ampersand. Otherwise you need to provide better details on your structure.

Comment: I missed the & that it shows in the link. What other details i should provide?

Comment: yes, do i need to change something in htaccess for the pagination?

Comment: Updated the question